# Can I use an sqlite database created for ios in android?

Tags: android, ios, string, sqlite

I would like to access the string-files stored in an sqlite database created for an ios application.
Any suggested methods to do this? I have searched all over the net but have not found anyone who has done this. 
I know it is possible to convert a plist file to an xml file, but in the future the app I am working on will get all the resources (including strings) from a server.

I hope someone can help with this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just include the SQLite database file as an asset in your app then use it like any other SQLite DB in Android.

You then mention that you will get resources from the server and I assume from your question that the data is currently in pLists so I think there may be 2 questions in one?

You might consider using JSON which, in many cases, is much faster than parsing XML.  I recently used "Sublime Text" to convert a bunch of plists to JSON.  It did a great job.  v1 of my app parsed pLists.  I tried SAX, DOM and the pull parser to find the quickest (SAX in this case) but, after conversion to JSON, v2 of the app is much, much faster.  I haven't measured it because I don't need to.  The user experience is enough.  Where I previously had to use a loading progress dialog on a particularly large pList, with the new JSON parser, the UI is responsive at all times.

Comment: You are right, the current app will just use an sqlite database (probably will be an asset on the external sd card or internal memory).
Question is, does it make sense to query the database every time a string is required for the layout? Does it not take up a lot of resources to query the DB every time a string is required?

The second version will use a hosted DB which will probably be accessed through json queries.